# Writing binary to file fails with "ascii codec can't encode character" error

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code I have now:

```
with open(file_name, "wb+") as destination:
    for chunk in file.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
```

The problem is, `file` contains some arbitrary text, arbitrary characters. For example, it may contain some Cyrillic characters. So, when I write to `file_name` I get this error message:

> ascii codec can't encode character \u0410

What is interesting is that on Windows server, I do not get this error, while when I'm using CentOS server, I get one.

If it matters, I'm using Python 3.

**EDIT**

I was able to minimize the problem. The whole problem is not even in reading the file, but in opening it. The file (encoded with windows-1252) is named "А-1.TAB", where "А" is a Cyrillic character. So, for some strange reason on CentOS, Python is unable to open files named in such a way. So now even this code does not work:

```
target = open(file_name, 'wb+')
```

**EDIT**

This is the contents of fstab, if it matters:

[image]

And this is the contents of mtab:

[image]

Besides, I should add that I tried to touch `12-A.TAB`, where A is a cyrillic character and it works good.

Comment: a [mcve] would be nice. for instance a standalone piece of code, with an input string that makes write choke

Comment: This input string produces the error message: "Точка 1"

Comment: On CentOS and not on Windows. It is important to notice this one more time. So, it may be a hard example to reproduce

Comment: Please add the lines where `file` is opened. The problem seems to be with the encoding used on file `file`.

Comment: The file uses windows-1252 encoding.

Comment: So, my task is as simple as my nose. I want to read from arbitrary file with arbitrary encoding and write data to another file. In PHP I can do this in a second, in Python I spent a whole day and still do not know how to do this.

Comment: If you don't decode the `file`, and perform the read-write operations directly in binary, would that solve your problem?

Comment: The catch is, I do not do any decoding and try to preform read-write operations in binary.

Comment: I was able to `open('tmp/А-1.TAB', 'wb+') and write to a file with that 'А-1.TAB' name (including the 'u\0410') on an older Fedora system's `ext4` filesystem, using Python 3.5.  It's possible the filesystem you're writing to does not allow non-ASCII filenames.  (Or maybe the network-mounting system is the problem, if it's an NFS, Samba, or otherwise-remote volume.)  What kind of filesystem is it, and how is it mounted?

Comment: Thanks, Kevin! I guess, you are right and your comment answers to my question, since my code does work on Windows and does not work on CentOS. Though, I'm not a Linux-guy and not quite sure how to check filesystem on CentOS and find a way it was mounted.

Comment: On Fedora (a close relative of CentOS), `/etc/fstab` contains the filesystems as they should be mounted, and `/etc/mtab` contains the filesystems that actually _are_ mounted (it's updated by the OS after every mount and unmount).  (For the record, I didn't find Unicode or character encoding mentioned in the various ext4 `man` pages, so turning it off might not even be an option for that filesystem.)  An easy test to see if the file can be created at all is to `touch '/path/to/А-1.TAB'` --- if the shell can't create it either, you know it's not just a problem with Python.

Comment: Since no one's attempted to answer you yet, you should [edit] your question (along with its title and tags) to address only the specific problem of creating Unicode filenames on whatever filesystem you're using.  You should also search for pre-existing questions related to Unicode filenames on whatever filesystem you're using (as well as Python).

Comment: Thanks, Kevin! I attached screens with contents from fstab and mtab. Besides I tried to manually touch 12-A.TAB and it works.

Comment: Strong suggestion:  [edit] your question, and copy & paste the _text_ of those images...  Even with glasses and zoomed in, I'm having trouble reading the second image.  (I'm getting old...)  Also, text can be searched; images can't.

Comment: It's clearly been a while since I used anything from Red Hat... I don't recognize most of your `/etc/fstab` filesystems, and I have _never_ seen an `/etc/mtab` like that.  The next step is to identify which one is the filesystem you're trying to write to --- the mount point will be the second column in both images.  Look for the one that matches the start of the `/path/to/your/file` (probably the `btrfs` mounted on `/home`, but I can't tell from here).  Then, you can ask a specific question about writing Unicode filenames to _that_ filesystem.  I won't be able to help with that, obviously.

Comment: Thank you so much, Kevin, for all your advices!